# $Φ : V → V$ all such linear mappings have same determinant, what does it mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, machine-learning

In the Book that I'm reading (Mathematics for Machine Learning), the following para is given, while listing the properties of a matrix determinant:

> Similar matrices (Definition 2.22) possess the same determinant.
> Therefore, for a linear mapping $Φ : V → V$ all transformation matrices
> $A_Φ$ of $Φ$ have the same determinant. Thus, the determinant is invariant
> to the choice of basis of a linear mapping.

I know that matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar if they satisfy $B=C^{-1}AC$.
I can prove that determinants of such $A$ and $B$ are equal using other properties of a determinant.

But beyond that I don't understand what this paragraph is saying. I can understand all matrices $Y$ such that $Y=X^{-1}AX$ have the same determinant as $A$, for varying $X$s.

But how do I connect this to linear mappings of the form $Φ : V → V$. What does $Φ : V → V$ mean here? Maybe someone can give me an example.

EDIT:
This video is pretty basic, but it helped me understand better
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4c5LQ5a4ek

Comment: It's saying that if $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ are two bases of $V$, then $[\Phi]_{\mathcal{B}_1}$ and $[\Phi]_{\mathcal{B}_2}$ are similar matrices and therefore have the same determinant.

Comment: Here $[Φ]_{B_1}$ and $[Φ]_{B_2}$ are mapping what to what?

Answer (score 2):

Given a linear transformation $T:V\to V$, if we choose a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $V$ we get an induced matrix $\Phi_{\mathcal{B}}:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^n$ representing the linear transformation with respect to this basis. Given another choice of basis $\mathcal{B}'$, there exists a change of basis matrix $P:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $\Phi_{\cal{B}}=P^{-1}\Phi_{\cal{B}'}P$. Hence, in light of this fact about determinants of similar matrices, we get
$$
\det \Phi_{\cal{B}}=\det(P^{-1}\Phi_{\mathcal{B}'}P)=\det\Phi_{\mathcal{B}'}.
$$
Remark: You can think of choosing a basis as choosing coordinates on $V$ (like you might do for a surface in calculus). Then the point is that we can define the determinant by choosing any coordinate system and writing the matrix representation of $T$ in coordinates, then computing there. The fact above says that this is independent of coordinate system and hence well defined as an invariant of the transformation $T$. The same applies for the trace of a map which you will probably encounter later if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 2):

Given an abstract finite dimensional (real) vector space $V$, a *[linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map)* $\Phi:V\to V$ is a map such that for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, and any $v,w\in V$:
$$
\Phi(v+w)=\Phi(v)+\Phi(w),\quad \Phi(\lambda v)=\lambda\Phi(v)
$$

Note that in this definition, no matrix is mentioned and $V$ is not necessarily $\mathbb{R}^n$ (although $V$ is *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}^n$).

If you choose an [ordered basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Ordered_bases_and_coordinates) $\beta$ for $V$, then $\Phi$ can be represented as an $n\times n$ matrix $B=[\Phi]_{\beta}$. If you choose another ordered basis $\alpha$ for $V$, then $\Phi$ can be represented as another $n\times n$ matrix $A=[\Phi]_{\alpha}$. In linear algebra, it is known that the two matrices $A$ and $B$ are "similar", and thus have the same determinant.

Since the determinant is invariant to the choice of basis, we can talk about the determinant of a linear mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $V$ is the vector space of quadratic polynomials and $\Phi$ is multiplication by $(1 + x)$ mod $x^3$.

Now let us consider two different bases for $V$. One will be $1, x, x^2$ and the other will be $1, (1 + x), (1 + x)^2$.

In the first basis we have

\begin{align}
\phi(1) &= 1 + x \\
\phi(x) &= \phantom{1 + {}}x + x^2 \\
\phi(x^2) &= \phantom{1 + x +{}} x^2.
\end{align}

In the second basis,

\begin{align}
\phi(1) &= \phantom{1 - 3} (1 + x) \\
\phi(1 + x) &= \phantom{1 - 3(1 + x) + 3}{}(1 + x)^2 \\
\phi((1 + x)^2) &= (1 + x)^3 \equiv 1 +3x+3x^2 \pmod{x^3} \\
&= 1 - 3(1 + x) + 3(1 + x)^2
\end{align}

The two matrices we get out of this are
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ and }
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And the statement/fact in question is that these two matrices are similar. If we were to write this as $A = PBP^{-1}$, the matrix $P$ would be the matrix corresponding to writing $\{1,(1+x),(1+x)^2\}$ in terms of the first basis. I.e.

$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$